# Issues with children of react router 6 rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I seen other post but those solutions have not worked for me. I Have a basic one and yet...does not work

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route index element={<Main />} />
      <Route path='/main' element={<Main />} >
        <Route path="test" element={<Test />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

every page, /main, /main/test, /main/fake all renders Main

I have also tried removing this part

```
<Route index element={<Main />} />
```

and this part

```
<Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
```

with no luck

Comment: See how you set up nested route https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#nested-routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add the `Outlet` component inside of `Main`? This is how the React Router v6 works, if you go to `/main/test` path it will render the `Main` component and `Test` component in a place where you specify the `Outlet` component

Comment: ah that was it i believe it, thank you